# Replacement for IdTransferringMergeEventListener when using Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate, spring, upgrade, spring-3, hibernate-4.x

Is there a Hibernate 4 version of `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.IdTransferringMergeEventListener`?

I'm attempting to upgrade my Spring 3.0.x + Hibernate 3.6 app to Spring 3.1 + Hibernate 4 but can't seem to find how to update this.

This specifically is referenced in my applicationContext as so:

```
<property name="eventListeners">
      <map>
        <entry key="merge">
          <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.IdTransferringMergeEventListener" />
        </entry>
      </map>
</property>
```

Just leaving it as is causes an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
```

presumably because Hibernate 4 does not have the class `DefaultMergeEventListener` anymore

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it looks like the class moved to `org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener`

Comment: Yea so I suppose I could create my own class that duplicates Springs IdTransferringMergeEventListener class from 3.0.x but utilizes the new Hibernate 4 class DefaultMergeEventListener.  I'm surprised Spring didn't create a Hibernate 4 compatible version though.  Wonder if it was an oversight or it's functionality is handled by another mechanism.

Comment: In my case we have upgraded spring and hibernate from v3 to v4. The eventListeners property was commented out and it was working fine. Is there any impact to doing so?

Answer (score 4):

The Spring folks decided not to implement this for Hibernate 4

From bug report in spring: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9634

> We intentionally kept Spring's Hibernate 4 support rather minimal, in order to stay close to the native Hibernate 4 ways of doing things. As a consequence, we have no plans to reintroduce IdTransferringMergeEventListener or any of our former LOB user types, all of which were special-purpose classes to work around issues that Hibernate should really solve itself - since they have nothing to do with Spring and caused repeated maintenance headaches on Spring's side.
>
> You're free to create your own version based on Spring's old IdTransferringMergeEventListener, of course. However, note that the way that event listeners can be registered has changed in Hibernate 4: This is not possible on a per-SessionFactory level anymore, hence Spring cannot support in its LocalSessionFactoryBean either. Check the corresponding Hibernate documentation and the corresponding reports on the Hibernate JIRA for details.
>
> Juergen